# Sort of double values outputting wrong data

Tags: java, sorting, selection

Ive had some issues with a program for university. I'm down too the last part of the assignment and what i thought would be the easy bit has quickly become the hardest. I'm asked to sort values from a `.cvs` file by the distance (values like `17.0123874627346,0.123761947`, etc)

**Here is my code:**

```
public void sortDistance() {
    System.out.println("before distance sort");
    for (int k = 0; k < ntracks; k++) {
        System.out.println(tracks[k].getDistance());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ntracks; i++) {
        //find the index of the minimum position
        int index = i;
        //looping through array of distances
        for (int j = i + 1; j < ntracks; j++) {
            if  (tracks[index].getDistance() < tracks[j].getDistance())             
            {
                //position j is new mimum index
                index = j;
            }
        }
        //swap the two values around so smallest becomes track index
        Track smallerTrack  = tracks[index]; 
        tracks[index] = tracks[i]; 
        tracks[i] = smallerTrack;
    }
    System.out.println(" after distnace sort");
    for (int k = 0; k < ntracks; k++) {
        System.out.println(tracks[k].getDistance());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float s[]={1,3,2};
Arrays.sort(s);

Comment: In java there in inbuilt method which can be used for sorting. Java.util.Arrays. it can sort primitive type data . see oracle docs for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to implement your own logic for sorting, you can use the methods provided..

```
Arrays.sort(tracks);

System.out.print(Arrays.toString(tracks));
```

[Source Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(double[]))

[Source Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(double[]))

Answer (score 0):

***TL:DR;***

- Use BigDecimal for high precision floating point numbers
- Use Comparable and Collections.sort() for sorting

***Full Answer***

It looks like you have a class that looks a little like this:

```
public class Track
    private float distance;
    public Track(float distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public float getDistance() {
        return this.distance;
    }
}
```

If that is the case, then I'd be tempted to change it up a bit and work with `BigDecimal`. `BigDecimal` is an object designed for working with decimal numbers when high precision is required. Since one of your sample distances has 13 decimal places, I'd be heading straight for `BigDecimal`.

So I'd change it up to look at bit like this:

```
public class Track
    private BigDecimal distance;
    public Track(String distance) {
        this.distance = new BigDecimal(distance);
    }
    public BigDecimal getDistance() {
        return this.distance;
    }
}
```

From here, you can rely on the fact that `BigDecimal` implements the Comparable interface, so it has a `compareTo` method. So you can implement `Comparable` for Track and then just `delegate` to the compareTo method on `BigDecimal`. So like this:

```
public class Track implements Comparable<Track> //Note we now implement an interface
    private float distance;
    public Track(float distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public float getDistance() {
        return this.distance;
    }
    public int compareTo(Track track) { //And our implementation just delegates to the BigDecimal compareTo method
        return this.distance.compareTo(track.getDistance());
    }
}
```

Once you have that in place, your sorting becomes super easy! you can replace all of your checking of the distances (because the `compareTo` on `BigDecimal` is doing it for you) and just call `Collections.sort()` on a list of the Track objects. Something like this would work:

```
public void sortDistance() {
    System.out.println("before distance sort");
    for (int k = 0; k < ntracks; k++) {
        System.out.println(tracks[k].getDistance());
    }

    List<Track> tracksList = Arrays.asList(tracks); //Convert to a list to use the Collections API
    Collections.sort(trackList);

    System.out.println(" after distnace sort");
    for (int k = 0; k < ntracks; k++) {
        System.out.println(tracksList.get(k).getDistance());
    }
}
```

I'll just finish off by saying that I've not ran any of this code, so it may not compile.

Also, here's some documentation for some of the things I've mentioned in case they're new concepts:

- [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)
- [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
- [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))